# In Java or Groovy, how to find file type of byte[]?

Tags: java

I have a `byte[]` that I got through the wire and want to verify that it's a JPEG. How can this be done?

Essentially, without having to write out a file, I'd like to do, more-or-less, what the `file` command does:

```
$ file aoeu.jpeg
aoeu.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.02
```

Comment: I once found a Java implementation of the `file` command in a CMS... But I'll be buggered if I know which one and where...

Comment: You can't without an extensive lookup. Look at the source code of file. It's a massive database.

Answer (score 6):

You can read the first and last bytes of the stream, and check the "Magic Number"

Basically, Magic Numbers are byte headers that identify the file contents

```
JPEG image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9.
```

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 1):

A JPEG image starts with **FF D8** so you can check if the first 2 bytes are **FF D8**.

Example code:

```
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];

    stream.read(bytes);

    if (bytes[0] != (byte)0xFF || bytes[1] != (byte)0xD8) {
        //no jpeg
    }

    stream.close()
```

Of course you can't be sure that the JPEG is valid and loads correct.

Comment: `bytes[0] != 0xFF` will always be `true`, because `0xFF` is an `int` literal representing `255`, and the maximum value in `bytes[0]` is `127`. You have the right idea, but the code is wrong.

Comment: oh yeah give me one moment, already late here :P

Comment: @jlordo should work now, another way would be to convert bytes[0] and bytes[1] to a unsigned byte but I think this is better

Answer (score 0):

If found this interesting comment:

> Similarly, a commonly used magic number for JPEG (Joint Photographic
>   Experts Group) image files is 0x4A464946, which is the ASCII
>   equivalent of JFIF (JPEG File Interchange Format). However, JPEG magic
>   numbers are not the first bytes in the file; rather, they begin with
>   the seventh byte.

Found it here http://www.linfo.org/magic_number.html

So you could look for:

```
Hex: FF D8 xx xx xx xx 4A 46 49 46 00
ASCII: ÿØÿè..JFIF.
```